# Display problem on second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

The desktop and every window is like 1" off the screen on every side of it, windows controls, menus, desktop panels are all outside the screen.

I tried `xrandr` but i was only able to make it worse. Any ideas what i can do to fix this?

[image: Uploaded a photo to make it clearer]

Comment: yes i am using hdmi. i had the same problem with windows 10 at first, but there was a 1776x1000 resolution option i could choose(the monitor still says its 1920x1080 when i power it up) and that solved it in win10. i tried xrandr to create a 1776x1000 mode but im just losing the display(sometimes an out of range message from the monitor itself)

Comment: I have a Sony television that has this problem (even when using chromecast or the cable box) but it works fine when I use VGA instead of HDMI.

Comment: i need it to run through hdmi though

Comment: is there anything i can use  in Windows 10 that would display the same infos as xrandr --current, either from command line or an app?

Comment: I think you can find this answer on the other related stackexchange sister site mostly about windows os: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Also, it helps to tag your answer with your gpu type, ati, nvidia, intel, etc.

Comment: this may help http://www.cnet.com/news/overscan-youre-not-seeing-the-whole-picture-on-your-tv/

Comment: My gpu is an ATI Radeon R5 230. Last link would have helped if that cheap Soyo monitor had any zoom/overscan options :)

Answer (score 1):

Just found out how to fix it, at least until I reboot, if anyone knows how to make this permanent let me know, for now I run a script on startup.

`xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set underscan on`